# Mysql dump, restore without overwriting local db credentials

Tags: mysql

I have an existing database,and sql dump file from similar db. Is there a way to restore it to this existing db without overwriting local credentials?

Dump is created by:

```
mysqldump --user=${user} --password=${password} my_database > "my_db_dump_${timestamp}.sql"
```

Also, should I clear the database before restoring into it?

```
mysql --user=${user} --password=${password} < "my_db_dump_${timestamp}.sql"
```

or can I just perform the above on existing db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dump created by `mysqldump` won't typically contain anything that would change user credentials.  `mysqldump` just "produc[es] a set of SQL statements that can be executed to reproduce the original database object definitions and table data." (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html)  As long as the database you're backing up isn't the internal "mysql" database, you're fine.

You also wouldn't use `mysqldump` to restore data -- again, it just generates a set of SQL statements.  So you'd use `mysql` to execute the generated SQL files.

As for whether you should "clear the database" before restoring into it, that question is a little more dependent on your database itself but typically the answer would be "yes."  (Empty the tables, that is; might not want to actually destroy them if they have table permissions defined, as of course that *would* be a change to your existing local credentials.) Since the mysqldump file is mostly just a bunch of CREATE and INSERT statements, it's pretty likely that INSERTs would just create duplicate values of anything already there.

But if in doubt, you can always just open up the generated .SQL file and see what the statements do and that'll guide how you prep for it.  It's a plain text file, nothing fancy.